# ANTLR LEXER RULE to have two rules, one will accept every characters including symbols and another will accept only characters

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, lexical-analysis, antlrworks

Is it possible in ANTLR LEXER RULE to have two rules, one will accept every characters including all symbols(like `(`,`)`,`_` etc) and another will accept only characters `a` to `z`?

Something like below:

```
String: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')*;
EVERYTHING:(.)*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

This is how ANTLR lexer decides which rule to use:
- whichever rule can match the longest sub-sequence of the input (starting form current position in the input)
- in case more rules can match this sub-sequence (i.e. it's a tie), the first rule (as defined in the grammar file) wins

So in your case, for alpha-only input, both rules will match it, but since `String` is further up in the grammar, it will be used. In case of non-alpha input, the `EVERYTHING` rule will be able to match a longer sub-sequence and therefore will be used.

Note however that as it's written, your `EVERYTHING` rule matches even spaces and newlines, so in this specific case `String` rule will be used only if the whole input is just alpha characters and nothing else; whole input will be matched as a single token in either case. So in real grammar, the `EVERTYHING` rule will be probably slightly different.

Comment: Okay, I tried to keep both lexer rules but it create issue saying String rule can never be used and fail. Please suggest what can be done to have both lexer rule and one should not affect other rule?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and add a minimal example grammar that is failing?